# Translate WGET shell script to Powershell

Tags: powershell, wget, invoke-webrequest

I'm trying to automate a process to auto update java on some servers and I need to download files from Oracle support website (a subscription is required in order to download out of support versions like JDK1.7).

Oracle provides WGET scripts to help with automation jobs, but I'm using AWS System Manager Run Command and I can't really use shell scripts, the script will be "pushed" on several windows servers where I don't want to install any additional shell modules just to let this script being executed.

Here is the .sh provided by Oracle:

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# Generated 5/19/22 9:26 PM
# Start of user configurable variables
#
LANG=C
export LANG

# Trap to cleanup cookie file in case of unexpected exits.
trap 'rm -f $COOKIE_FILE; exit 1' 1 2 3 6

# SSO username
printf 'SSO UserName:'
read SSO_USERNAME



# Path to wget command
WGET=/usr/bin/wget

# Log directory and file
LOGDIR=.
LOGFILE=$LOGDIR/wgetlog-$(date +%m-%d-%y-%H:%M).log

# Print wget version info
echo "Wget version info:
------------------------------
$($WGET -V)
------------------------------" > "$LOGFILE" 2>&1

# Location of cookie file
COOKIE_FILE=$(mktemp -t wget_sh_XXXXXX) >> "$LOGFILE" 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ] || [ -z "$COOKIE_FILE" ]
then
 echo "Temporary cookie file creation failed. See $LOGFILE for more details." |  tee -a "$LOGFILE"
 exit 1
fi
echo "Created temporary cookie file $COOKIE_FILE" >> "$LOGFILE"

# Output directory and file
OUTPUT_DIR=.

#
# End of user configurable variable
#

# The following command to authenticate uses HTTPS. This will work only if the wget in the environment
# where this script will be executed was compiled with OpenSSL. 
#
 $WGET  --secure-protocol=auto --save-cookies="$COOKIE_FILE" --keep-session-cookies  --http-user "$SSO_USERNAME" --ask-password  "https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/Services/download" -O /dev/null 2>> "$LOGFILE"

# Verify if authentication is successful
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
 echo "Authentication failed with the given credentials." | tee -a "$LOGFILE"
 echo "Please check logfile: $LOGFILE for more details."
else
 echo "Authentication is successful. Proceeding with downloads..." >> "$LOGFILE"

 $WGET  --load-cookies="$COOKIE_FILE" "https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/Services/download/p18143322_1800_MSWIN-x86-64.zip?aru=24758442&patch_file=p18143322_1800_MSWIN-x86-64.zip" -O "$OUTPUT_DIR/p18143322_1800_MSWIN-x86-64.zip"   >> "$LOGFILE" 2>&1 

fi

# Cleanup
rm -f "$COOKIE_FILE"
echo "Removed temporary cookie file $COOKIE_FILE" >> "$LOGFILE"

enter code here
```

And this is my Powershell script:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$uaString   = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::FireFox
$LoginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 
'https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/Services/download/p18143322_1800_MSWIN-x86-64.zip?aru=24758442&patch_file=p18143322_1800_MSWIN-x86-64.zip'  -UserAgent $uaString

$Session
$loginForm= $LoginResponse.Forms | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 'LoginForm'}
$loginForm.Fields["sso_username"] = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
$loginForm.Fields["ssopassword"] = 'xxxxxxxxx'
#$loginForm.Method
#$loginForm.Action
#$loginForm.Fields


$ProfileResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://login.oracle.com/oam/server/sso/auth_cred_submit' -Method $loginForm.Method -Body $loginForm.Fields -SessionVariable 'Session' -UserAgent $uaString -UseBasicParsing

$ProfileResponse

$download = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/Services/download/p18143322_1800_MSWIN-x86-64.zip?aru=24758442&patch_file=p18143322_1800_MSWIN-x86-64.zip' -UserAgent $uaString -WebSession $Session  -OutFile ".\test" -Verbose -Debug 

$download

$Session = ''
```

When I execute the second Invoke-WebRequest I think that I succesfully logged in(this only after adding the -UserAgent, before that in the response I could see that it was still asking me for username and password):

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : 
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"  dir="ltr">
                        <head>
                        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
                        <title>Single Sign-...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    Pragma: no-cache
                    X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 005rsjcxHgR6ATGEmzomkJ0000u40000P7
                    X-Frame-Options: SameOrigin
                    X-XSS-Protection: 0
                    Content-Length: 1794
                    Cache-Control:...
Forms             : 
Headers           : {[Connection, keep-alive], [Pragma, no-cache], [X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID, 005rsjcxHgR6ATGEmzomkJ0000u40000P7], [X-Frame-Options, SameOrigin]...}
Images            : {@{outerHTML=<img src="/oam/pages/images/login_logo.png" />; tagName=IMG; src=/oam/pages/images/login_logo.png}}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : 
RawContentLength  : 1794
```

But when I execute the last Invoke-WebRequest I only get this response:

```
<html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function submitForm()
{
var hash = location.hash;
if (hash) {
if(hash.indexOf("#") == -1){
hash="#"+hash
}
document.myForm.action = document.myForm.action+hash;
}
document.myForm.submit();
}
</script><head><base target="_self"></head><body onLoad="submitForm()"><noscript><p>JavaScript is required. Enable JavaScript to use OAM Server.</p></noscript><form action="https://login.oracle.com/mysso/signon.jsp" method="post" name="myForm"><!------------ DO NOT REMOVE -------------><!----- loginform renderBrowserView -----><!-- Required for SmartView Integration --><input type="hidden" name="bmctx" value="05C65B855F507509F2A50E4187F746B908003F815E8CAC65124394831AC5D9EF"><input type="hidden" name="contextType" value="external"><input type="hidden" name="username" value="string"><input type="hidden" name="contextValue" value="%2Foam"><input type="hidden" name="challenge_url" value="https%3A%2F%2Flogin.oracle.com%2Fmysso%2Fsignon.jsp"><input type="hidden" name="password" value="secure_string"><input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="390581305062349926"><input type="hidden" name="authn_try_count" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="OAM_REQ" value="VERSION_4~uIlOJ1NvMkBeT3fx5VGkI3a%2fwc%2fSY3cX29PzPvt%2fiIvDmVKaP2w7YhJhkLBUJnkTAfbWrRGylnuo80FKQUzkwcDOp%2ban9xDQSA1BeaI6n6M%2bKhe%2fGJx7QWWEalf6Y%2fBYRh%2bc%2bXsaRMAeVc%2fRx%2bxVR3yFtB4ph3qjp300iMTR5rGR3oMx3APqDNt%2bOwtJnYZ0pvCIQUrAVllkOfjTreZGHMmUZj85wYNIQQGX6D%2fST1nSAKiWoWqChyZd9e90DetjO%2bxmmUNzVeRRQmOxRpMUgB4JvkI2TUt3%2fG0cgV4XjaeUJ39L%2bt9s2GhkpUoxIGSG4kRCQcL2k7qClF%2fpKPKQDmjGhrRoJSpMv5ifAtEvovBO7mqVfGY%2b8fnKsACSl9gnvrUUS1A%2fdUSuM6pdxPjMgpRQem3j2ZbQURyN9BBlDWtmk6Mp1BeVmtyk728LQWv%2bIIMkqFyN2Ww7OVqm9kC0y8cmqv8T5w81DGg6Rm2bG379StK9Y0nx2PWCDhS9n7N5CFGpdjfE603OcK1jTgkBulnrCbzYhtzwGYRfZ3pXM067XJfyyNP3yjnjejlqXBb5mkIBghf11ooZf3Yn%2bSWUq2xENXn3djkwB7eoPMdavTFWH4f0hi2uWfn955To2N7aBusU2OF3H0%2felc6mLbaI36MigMTCxbRD%2bktuDGyYhRkJUrQcoow3A4fpPFaCKxVb6ldli4yNXH1aQ0n7%2fF%2f4hMX24hJdHar5EA1IPhJ3tORYneIGhEQH9nDzy2aBQKBjPJHpDcx10aq3URx%2fu9FlfBLDet7XAPu6G6J3kL9ny90y6EZQq5ZEJGJeYR41EZRCU9g%2fVoJkVjseyiydoRdqqUSwG3ejZOm6XoZZnlwWLm9ysMKgtF2tauGigytgkaZI0y%2bYATghxS0R9dyEFd0nztNk5WShaQ3P18NMEOxq29Oc3LuIRET9JMChJgKScm3WqfqrGtNJGqH%2f3ZYZ1535vcUvsGVirKzYOTVuLAol7Pl9LWPYxMtOI45%2bGLC0kaVPZsgeZm3arGlim0aORou3Usjo7yONbBaJHvUGlkPiBecGT%2b8mquU5c8b7MwK3v6L%2br9rctK%2fPeq8jAkgOpeTuLEmm%2fXhznE0DcJaaB7cOdYKeUvB1kB448MNiZWPilAzWF3o6waim9Fcrqiy9%2fiR3FOjoK%2f0gOACExPeLOu9rRP3wRXuo1yMCNLpjLvUX8I2xo019uOTHwb4qFjocZB1VuExmzFQLrKFGrQj9zERcVlvK8yfQerpjVfkSTqHDHlJf8NbkkcOf%2fh%2b4GP9R0zgpU%2bj4wkW%2blEVC3qNwlvM6eSZ690mlTzeLdiHDtCoi%2f9Zk1U%2bGtOFMwDhES0ZNUijMnCjuhi4pMqUVVtrhy3%2fAI1h52DDudg8vMzfeSJeZyFk5n4WXOdkmNC6dWJkD6FjLlfjnTzzT6ocFnAB3UrQFcuMAIhOPRS3Zxm%2bT9UcZ4Xg9etZ263oujczmP%2f23r2VkvOxCCLPs9Kh3cBFvEBBT254HxJnJC0H3sBf0tct9pbW7sr2SgbeKy%2fmNTcHzxdShKyg%2b8gB6fgRQ2D%2f4%2bISNs%2bMOkwvF%2fV%2f62ngLnbG8QTTBb5AiFTXjF2zpnBX8FmdmkMdHgjsgCP7eBy%2bav9o0kZAVVliNoHvuOOBzg6KcNaA%2bFu4HXa5FSgUnpW6OADeGmq%2bAfd%2b3tBpcW5AtusAN1utfKDM82HKnB7hvpRTJ9nuDaiNci0WrrabJU7ahiZDByeiZTgh%2fo1h2h20Cll90R0O2JrTrAJyIyjk6dkS9Siq4k9%2fCVacJupeTrdKWE1ARrS3QSmeQWm%2f%2bjFKFBq6CzUvXyXWe9a41VZhvLcSFd9XLZHM3XxhUcPwaSSoodU2GGSBB0gc2ywEOY501VbSkfA8YnASETMD7zVP8%2bbZC6GbAw6UtgQIcCI8KXFSQc3qD9xU4VV6IHkZRIjzeX2%2fngr11WVpfWYlQhMbc7YNGsVVMdZ9y9sqmL6rgIJjX5QWBGw9rCaVMFXTZkKIg5qkgIbaiy938ekXW6gNs3s8UOa26qVPX3F1S6WREyPkFHiPlrbIoMm8RIpTpmFhz6a1Qhw5r95yvgQPIEOjA7Fdy3tV653owh8N3WG4Pfr59s%2fQhOlirDGqKw95OR9Xz1pOtD9X74nB4Q8hZfHZXf9%2foO6brGdatkkUnbN6DorLPYlMroAvlE4kp1iOm9%2b3i7NLUH3AfWgck1X7dzdPwhGHuNySA194CmoWk4jQHoU4D2UT8NGUy8M%2fbYdYetXum7oUU0sQ7OfQ6F9%2fS45sTvgXUbxi1l%2byOvJGP3vkWuFvwVhA0WBWVk22Sj84byJ9F%2f3cXmrc%2f0ukAOc1ledHuSqmwQAOMTWtSo6vv9nJkmVBL1kx%2b7m%2f7BkeWObD%2fxxhwtfUMFKicuscv%2f9gWML8lEzu3mFdzjRoErUFX6sGTRWlXl9OUdY0zDsbQrZcsUStATtgc2eP2%2fZtif5Z79cDhjFxbHHG2cx3gIbEZRoHFsTZsHW2zCKzL%2fO9Gh5jIkW14CdsIa5rXMoljSv98Z%2fnTSf%2b%2bjk344IeSFfnCVnUq8wHfM0238A%3d%3d"><input type="hidden" name="locale" value="en_US"><input type="hidden" name="resource_url" value="https%253A%252F%252Fupdates.oracle.com%252FOrion%252FServices%252Fdownload%252Fp18143322_1800_MSWIN-x86-64.zip%253Faru%253D24758442%2526patch_file%253Dp18143322_1800_MSWIN-x86-64.zip"></form></body></html>
```

I think that it's being redirected again to the login page.. Am I not using correctly the -WebSession?

**Update:** I changed the script setting the url for the first 2 calls both to: https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/Services/download/

Now I'm sure that actually the login is not working because this is the response I get:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <html>
                    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    function submitForm()
                    {
                    var hash = location.hash;
                    if (hash) {
                    if(hash.indexOf("#") == -1){
                    hash="#"+hash
                    }
                    document.myForm.action = documen...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 005rsl8r3auFk3KimT_uWJ0003MG000Q55
                    Content-Length: 3537
                    Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
                    Date: Sat, 21 May 2022 21:28:14 GMT
                    Set-Co...
Forms             : {LoginForm}
Headers           : {[Connection, keep-alive], [X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID, 005rsl8r3auFk3KimT_uWJ0003MG000Q55], [Content-Length, 3537], [Content-Type, text/html;charset=UTF-8]...}
Images            : {@{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<img src="/mysso/sso_loginui/sso-f17v2-bgimg.jpg">; outerText=; tagName=IMG; src=/mysso/sso_loginui/sso-f17v2-bgimg.jpg}}
InputFields       : {@{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<input name="v" type="hidden" value="v1.4">; outerText=; tagName=INPUT; name=v; type=hidden; value=v1.4}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; 
                    outerHTML=<input name="request_id" type="hidden" value="-2162099557289357143">; outerText=; tagName=INPUT; name=request_id; type=hidden; value=-2162099557289357143}, 
                    @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<input name="OAM_REQ" type="hidden" value="VERSION_4~Z7letcxh1HmQLxiPiKnprgpaKDYqYKoi8bKrGBSNxY67dgXw1Zt9SLZzsulrD7cvDYdJJ1LMhqXr8Zz7S
                    pdyebCjzBR7mLaJmGDumtkEvsqtH2oqfhS00v3YyhVCkAuO2rqE9cYxmsklmv%2bBeR76wS5mHHVF4Qx2aXxFIyxRLlwY0ZOYJ0cSylHuiD3QVfox7JnXoAVB5QFF3iNfq6jrOx4IMUuMp9SDz3iXy%2fxWFgE9blj5RuIe6WU
                    mR6ojJ6aw%2bdmyP8ovAKXLBpmKROgzDVt92FyfzwB%2b88xgPc3J%2fCVw5dOcyeivZ%2f%2f7X7jqFwzl8s7EAU8G9z7HeWdsEl6lKRXip%2bEW0Aqau30e%2b1M2NpTTa5srv8abEU%2b51GuoQWa7a0TIWC44%2bkBbFjo
                    yj3UAwIDO9XlX47oLcO5BoWjf6R%2bYByB1p0kPt3XTMAnM%2facPsU50vendRO%2fbUeB%2fzUbljG8%2ffBrCYwIkJQ2c%2b3ryg6AuLjFoXOPiV3U6Cqj6%2fDcK6tscGUqDjaAPwIT6sFWIBWZX%2fRfXIu18FsGG0t%2b
                    VvWufqn2bY2a5LqyyafEWkeqXiyLAUBc2f8gXCImiIzPIIKJrw9wUSE4PgqKCPEFqxviiNNMoCyDcdVIU8MZW6XvvlvAQ4znRBfGqhlUyvi2y9XzCVUnolLhOJ1BPtwi%2bf5dOPyLwywCxCD7rS0%2bRm%2bwtVFZCmmjxYPF
                    Rg5qY2zCgv1NyAm81wXvc6JtBUoW8Z1DlhSUFiPOnvZCef0NJ6OcVelTy9WmdwbPEVAg446rqm8xKZ7D%2fmwjFS9Uka1dwQez7d%2f9A9ButayM1LyiBWaHIt760Rb92zqzma3tGrKK6pTRlojwT%2b%2fnKv4LiW9fVzb2T2
                    v0CK0vzswouCCNNk3CX8muAm%2b0ZFxcOjYzRpPFvi%2b5tlkRDH8n0Om%2f%2bUtcR73ABOlSN22hhzFwLYUir22Vasg0ry02t7yOVt8674nGKzDeclzSIVyVUniG3FksZmBb7rLT0UUSP6h3iIJPwKtoEeYJ8SYAJkpZo9Rs
                    PhqO2wyr5pGOAu%2faazY4REkr%2bCGYA0Jwi5%2bfUVW7BQgBoHJPglPpDZP0AaQodclakSVXyHZM2cb5ppqvY4YdNp3kdITLuYgOJVTaMxfR9Es6K98mmbcAGspBBC%2fuETDLBQSFcFFtRfIs8MF8BiyjFcIZ1LSb4Jzj79
                    MYOLQVL2wNkjjJPVj6XNhCKH7zKkDa%2b4SWAYVO06PhB6CC2iAQVHPtRBNYsaaF%2byI5ZvutvngcIrmrSQnnJ7Jsb4Lsc1x3Df2JuSe4V5hrwg2I2%2bYxw0fN1UrE%2fWa8lBdLEf5DpnCd6xlnh64YWsiWjELQfY3cPx1h
                    KpQKJWtu0IW6Oa%2f6QDUUoX2pqS7aYoTKI7WQ4I7cy1qUMD6LSzp2Ix2sGW0Wyn4W%2b3H4Ku%2bIeRhE%2fBm3%2f7E1AVrHxskIjh4dFDjUSF%2bDxZIUVpNxQjk0G3VCYfTA3CkJ7IZoGvr8CbyB0X7%2fUuGJPSsop%2b
                    QxDYk3S1zzTA1%2bP6Ei9stIxojOprjJEUoaKkipSU8mAegYhXKGDgCVsqTB3UpUpD1dRiv3J1w9yhwf%2bREeIi80tX1OTaXjBTS6enxF0jIN6%2fh1jqr5uaG12l91MQRVrdPwugxA90yxo%2biABxHcELEJ0m66ycOymddf
                    df8VRqchFdgzUUk%2boaGdT4bcNEk8TIFHS6F4Y9aI%2f5dkPNmNunk4etOJT5XLuHEtG4XFADLM67u1CAPwpXi3ixIkYnjBEyAKBNMCh1ur0elNaFGl%2b1IKZ8XisHSdGChmxOjWN2nM9Qgh9m1ZomcSTvxqb7bqMpH5lHOX
                    8PnvU1OwDlFW0CXG8lXCax%2bZvA1YdK8Xfl04PV3YhR2x2plyPnFyIqzrkc%2fXOtB9%2bV5LBPmv23v8ISKPnFH4ra7O5kiZ6xN9064L2O7dRuVX8kF9FXKEanjyeKsMWfn%2bnxjd%2bQZ8B%2f1fj">; outerText=; 
                    tagName=INPUT; name=OAM_REQ; type=hidden; value=VERSION_4~Z7letcxh1HmQLxiPiKnprgpaKDYqYKoi8bKrGBSNxY67dgXw1Zt9SLZzsulrD7cvDYdJJ1LMhqXr8Zz7SpdyebCjzBR7mLaJmGDumtkEvsqtH2oq
                    fhS00v3YyhVCkAuO2rqE9cYxmsklmv%2bBeR76wS5mHHVF4Qx2aXxFIyxRLlwY0ZOYJ0cSylHuiD3QVfox7JnXoAVB5QFF3iNfq6jrOx4IMUuMp9SDz3iXy%2fxWFgE9blj5RuIe6WUmR6ojJ6aw%2bdmyP8ovAKXLBpmKROgz
                    DVt92FyfzwB%2b88xgPc3J%2fCVw5dOcyeivZ%2f%2f7X7jqFwzl8s7EAU8G9z7HeWdsEl6lKRXip%2bEW0Aqau30e%2b1M2NpTTa5srv8abEU%2b51GuoQWa7a0TIWC44%2bkBbFjoyj3UAwIDO9XlX47oLcO5BoWjf6R%2bY
                    ByB1p0kPt3XTMAnM%2facPsU50vendRO%2fbUeB%2fzUbljG8%2ffBrCYwIkJQ2c%2b3ryg6AuLjFoXOPiV3U6Cqj6%2fDcK6tscGUqDjaAPwIT6sFWIBWZX%2fRfXIu18FsGG0t%2bVvWufqn2bY2a5LqyyafEWkeqXiyLAUB
                    c2f8gXCImiIzPIIKJrw9wUSE4PgqKCPEFqxviiNNMoCyDcdVIU8MZW6XvvlvAQ4znRBfGqhlUyvi2y9XzCVUnolLhOJ1BPtwi%2bf5dOPyLwywCxCD7rS0%2bRm%2bwtVFZCmmjxYPFRg5qY2zCgv1NyAm81wXvc6JtBUoW8Z1
                    DlhSUFiPOnvZCef0NJ6OcVelTy9WmdwbPEVAg446rqm8xKZ7D%2fmwjFS9Uka1dwQez7d%2f9A9ButayM1LyiBWaHIt760Rb92zqzma3tGrKK6pTRlojwT%2b%2fnKv4LiW9fVzb2T2v0CK0vzswouCCNNk3CX8muAm%2b0ZFx
                    cOjYzRpPFvi%2b5tlkRDH8n0Om%2f%2bUtcR73ABOlSN22hhzFwLYUir22Vasg0ry02t7yOVt8674nGKzDeclzSIVyVUniG3FksZmBb7rLT0UUSP6h3iIJPwKtoEeYJ8SYAJkpZo9RsPhqO2wyr5pGOAu%2faazY4REkr%2bCG
                    YA0Jwi5%2bfUVW7BQgBoHJPglPpDZP0AaQodclakSVXyHZM2cb5ppqvY4YdNp3kdITLuYgOJVTaMxfR9Es6K98mmbcAGspBBC%2fuETDLBQSFcFFtRfIs8MF8BiyjFcIZ1LSb4Jzj79MYOLQVL2wNkjjJPVj6XNhCKH7zKkDa%
                    2b4SWAYVO06PhB6CC2iAQVHPtRBNYsaaF%2byI5ZvutvngcIrmrSQnnJ7Jsb4Lsc1x3Df2JuSe4V5hrwg2I2%2bYxw0fN1UrE%2fWa8lBdLEf5DpnCd6xlnh64YWsiWjELQfY3cPx1hKpQKJWtu0IW6Oa%2f6QDUUoX2pqS7aY
                    oTKI7WQ4I7cy1qUMD6LSzp2Ix2sGW0Wyn4W%2b3H4Ku%2bIeRhE%2fBm3%2f7E1AVrHxskIjh4dFDjUSF%2bDxZIUVpNxQjk0G3VCYfTA3CkJ7IZoGvr8CbyB0X7%2fUuGJPSsop%2bQxDYk3S1zzTA1%2bP6Ei9stIxojOprj
                    JEUoaKkipSU8mAegYhXKGDgCVsqTB3UpUpD1dRiv3J1w9yhwf%2bREeIi80tX1OTaXjBTS6enxF0jIN6%2fh1jqr5uaG12l91MQRVrdPwugxA90yxo%2biABxHcELEJ0m66ycOymddfdf8VRqchFdgzUUk%2boaGdT4bcNEk8T
                    IFHS6F4Y9aI%2f5dkPNmNunk4etOJT5XLuHEtG4XFADLM67u1CAPwpXi3ixIkYnjBEyAKBNMCh1ur0elNaFGl%2b1IKZ8XisHSdGChmxOjWN2nM9Qgh9m1ZomcSTvxqb7bqMpH5lHOX8PnvU1OwDlFW0CXG8lXCax%2bZvA1Yd
                    K8Xfl04PV3YhR2x2plyPnFyIqzrkc%2fXOtB9%2bV5LBPmv23v8ISKPnFH4ra7O5kiZ6xN9064L2O7dRuVX8kF9FXKEanjyeKsMWfn%2bnxjd%2bQZ8B%2f1fj}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<input 
                    name="locale" type="hidden" value="">; outerText=; tagName=INPUT; name=locale; type=hidden; value=}...}
Links             : {@{innerHTML=Oracle; innerText=Oracle; outerHTML=<a tabindex="9" href=" https://www.oracle.com/index.html&#10;">Oracle</a>; outerText=Oracle; tagName=A; tabindex=9; 
                    href= https://www.oracle.com/index.html&#10;}, @{innerHTML= Forgot username?
                    ; innerText= Forgot username? ; outerHTML=<a tabindex="6" href=" https://profile.oracle.com/myprofile/account/forgot-username.jspx&#10;" target="_blank"> Forgot username?
                    </a>; outerText= Forgot username? ; tagName=A; tabindex=6; href= https://profile.oracle.com/myprofile/account/forgot-username.jspx&#10;; target=_blank}, @{innerHTML= 
                    Forgot password?
                    ; innerText= Forgot password? ; outerHTML=<a tabindex="8" href=" https://profile.oracle.com/myprofile/account/forgot-password.jspx&#10;" target="_blank"> Forgot password?
                    </a>; outerText= Forgot password? ; tagName=A; tabindex=8; href= https://profile.oracle.com/myprofile/account/forgot-password.jspx&#10;; target=_blank}, @{innerHTML= 
                    Need help?
                    ; innerText= Need help? ; outerHTML=<a tabindex="4" href=" https://www.oracle.com/corporate/contact/help.html&#10;" target="_blank"> Need help?
                    </a>; outerText= Need help? ; tagName=A; tabindex=4; href= https://www.oracle.com/corporate/contact/help.html&#10;; target=_blank}...}
ParsedHtml        : System.__ComObject
RawContentLength  : 3537
```